# iOS: Select a tab after app has loaded in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

In my app I usually want to start the user in the first tab bar (as set up in Storyboard). However depending on certain settings, I want to select another tab whenever the app is loaded or just enters the foreground again. How can I do this in the app delegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in App delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method for selecting particular tab index.

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
tabController.selectedIndex = selectedTabIndex;
```

Comment: Just did, had to wait 10 minutes :-P